# Visual Studio 2017 install hangs at 13%

Tags: visual-studio

I have tried to install Visual Studio 2017 multiple times. Every time I try, it locks up at 13%.

The message displayed is

> Applying Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebToolsExtensions

The package is acquired at 100%.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [You are not alone](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24202/installation-sticks-at-applying-microsoftvisualstu.html). Looks like the problem could be related to anti-virus. User Darren Rose wrote "For me I just had to disable AVG Internet Security completely for install to finish"

Comment: Download the installer media again. If it keeps doing it, your operating system is hosed for some reason. Reinstall.

Comment: Some programmers' machines just *need* to get infected.  They are much ahead by the malware disabling the anti-malware product :)

Comment: I have had similar problems when I try to install anywhere but the default folder.

Comment: I was trying to install to another folder. I am trying the default now. It just made it past 13%. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

User "theGleep" above was correct. Once I installed to the default directory, it worked. Now Visual Studio 2017 won't connect to TFS.... sigh.